# Python - Add to dataframe conditioned median values

Tags: python

I have a basic question.

DataFrame:

```
Name   Value
Albert  5
Dudu    7
Albert  15
Dudu    10
Albert  2
Dudu    4
```

How to add an additional column with medians for each Name?

To get this output:

```
Name   Value   Median
Albert  5       5
Dudu    7       7
Albert  15      5
Dudu    10      7
Albert  2       5
Dudu    4       7
```

thanks

Comment: See marked duplicate. The solution is generalizable to arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Transformations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df['Median'] = df.groupby('Name').transform('median')
```